# Proper Steps to Shutdown NetApp FAS 3020 with Shelves?

Tags: netapp

I have a netapp with several shelves that is going to have to be moved.  Various servers have NFS mounts from it.  What is the proper procedure to shut it down and start it up?  I would guess shutting down the servers before the netapp and then the otherway when starting it up would make sense... what about the netapp itself?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as the filer itself, "halt" from the CLI is pretty much all you need to know.
(You'd obviously want be sure that no servers are using it).
Power off the head, then the shelves, and do in reverse after you've moved.

http://now.netapp.com has some valuable best-practice guides for this sort of scenario - as an aside, if you're physically moving the netapp, it would be very wise to make sure that your netapp support is current.

Comment: Yes, this, good answer

Comment: Ya I have a NOW account, but was feeling a bit lazy and figured someone could just spoon feed me the nice short and to the point answer :-)

Comment: I'd go with `halt -f` to inhibit failover.

Answer (score 3):

#### Shutdown - Perform steps on both heads of the filer

```
Cf status
Cf disable
Cf status

Cifs terminate

sysstsat -x
lun stats -i 10
```

If the numbers are not close to zero determine why there is traffic.

```
Halt
```

- Shows halt on the front
- Use powerswitch to turn them all off.

#### Powerup

1. Turn on the disk shelves first ….wait 1 minute
2. Turn on the heads (Ones with LCD's on the front)

   ```
   Cf status
   Cf enable
   Cf status
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to add a couple steps if no physical access is available.

SP status

After the HALT command you can cut the power to the building

Once you are safe to start the filer back up you can access the console via the SP/RLM management port from the IP you got from the SP status info

Log in via naroot

system console

boot_ontap

once both nodes in the filer pair are up you can enable the cluster

cf enable

Answer (score 0):

If you trigger a halt -s would be the cleaner way for shutting down a filer.

Performs a clean system shutdown. The behavior of this command is different across releases. In Data ONTAP releases prior to 8.0.4 and 8.1.2 the end result of this command is to power off the controller. The user has to power on the controller using the RLM or SP. In Data ONTAP releases 8.0.4, 8.1.2 and beyond, it will no longer power off the controller. Instead, it will halt at the LOADER prompt. For platforms that have FRU attention LEDs on the motherboard, Data ONTAP will clear these LEDs when subsequently booted. This applies only to Data ONTAP 8.0 and later.